# CustomTicks Package not working

Tags: packages

I need nice ticks for scientific figures so I downloaded the [CustomTicks](https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5599/) package in a certain folder and installed the CustomTicks.m file on my Mathematica 12.0 through the file>Install menu and named it CustomTicks as well.

According to the package documentation, this following code using `LinTicks` and `LogTicks`

```
 Plot[
    {Log10[Cosh[x]],Log10[Sinh[x]]},{x,0,10},
    PlotRange->{{-0.0001,4},{-0.5,2.5}},
    FrameTicks->{LinTicks,LogTicks,None,None},
    Axes->False,Frame->True,ImageSize->72*3
    ]
```

should yield a logarithmic plot with the following ticks 
[image]

However when I call the package through `Needs` and execute the same exact code

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"]
Plot[{Log10[Cosh[x]], Log10[Sinh[x]]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.0001, 4}, {-0.5, 2.5}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {LinTicks, LogTicks, None, None}, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 72*3]
```

I get this

[image]

This is the default output from Mathematica that is produced even when `FrameTicks -> {LinTicks, LogTicks, None, None}` is removed or set to `Automatic`. Calling `LinTicks` and `LogTicks` seems to produce no effects at all.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: If it's just a matter of logarithmic scaling, have you already seen the `ScalingFunctions` option?

Comment: @J.M.'stechnicaldifficulties I am aware of LogPlot but I want to make use of this package's capabilities in producing nice-looking customizable tick marks and etc. suitable for scientific figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Plot[{Log10[Cosh[x]], Log10[Sinh[x]]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.0001, 4}, {-0.5, 2.5}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {LinTicks, LogTicks}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 ImageSize -> 72*3]
```

Removed the None(s) and now it seems to work almost.

[image]

I think the Syntax is different now. Check the FrameTicks documentation!

```
Plot[{Log10[Cosh[x]], Log10[Sinh[x]]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-0.0001, 4}, {-0.5, 2.5}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{LogTicks, None}, {LinTicks, None}}, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 72*3]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!